# Any way to compute watts a processor is using?

Tags: cpu, cpu-usage, turbo-boost

I have an [Intel 10900](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/compare.html?productIds=199328) (non K and non F). The [TDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_design_power) is listed at 65 watts however my understanding is that this is the max heat generated at the baseline clock which is 2.8 GHz. My processor is running in boost mode using 4.6 GHz. Does that mean that at 100% utilization at this clock speed it is consuming proportional power - 107 watts?

Comment: You might consider a basic power measurement with a decent Wattmeter.   Set up the computer running the CPU connected to the wattmeter that is connected to the AC power. Get it running, make sure disk usage is very low, turn the screen off and then the measurement should reasonably reflect CPU power consumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [HWINFO](https://www.hwinfo.com/) to monitor the current power consumed by the CPU package. You can find said measurements in the "Sensors" tab (alongside with a lot of other useful information).

Comment: That did it. End result was 112 W so not far from what I was guessing.